# Cygwin, Git, win32 error when checking out tag

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

I'm trying to checkout a tag of a repository using git, via cygwin, on a Windows XP platform.  I get the following error:

`$ git checkout v0.4.2
      0 [main] git 6028 C:\cygwin\bin\git.exe: * fatal error - could not load C:\WINDOWS\system32\winmm.dll, Win32 error 487`

Has anyone experienced this? I see a little bit of chatter about it around the web, but I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: *Do* you have a `C:\WINDOWS\system32\winmm.dll`? I do, on my XP machine.

Comment: @boldewyn - yes the dll is present.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cygwin problem. Git has nothing to do with winmm.dll(windows multimedia dll).

If you can, use [Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)(former msysgit). If that doesn't suit you, then you should try updating your cygwin installation to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to move to git for windows, but I would rather stay in a unix environment. The version of cygwin I am using is the latest (installed yesterday).

Comment: Git for Windows includes bash and all common tools like ls, grep, cat, vim(from cygwin also). Give it a try, till you crack that issue open, rather then standing still, this way you can continue whatever you were doing rather then halting because of that seemingly totally unrelated issue to Git.

Comment: Unfortunately, msysgit is also prone to this kind of problem: https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=176 , https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=133 , http://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/1403 . I've hit this problem with [Git-1.8.3-preview20130601.exe](https://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.8.3-preview20130601.exe), after about a week after installing it and using it constantly every day.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Git to newer version. I faced the same problem and upgrading Git to version 1.7.4 resolved it.

You may choose to upgrade only git to avoid breaking other utilities.